# В чём проблема silero torch

Tags: python, pytorch

Мой код:

```
import torch
import sounddevice as sd
import time

language = 'ru'
model_id = 'ru_v3'
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'aidar'
put_accent = True
put_yo = True
device = torch.device('cpu')
text = 'Привет'

model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                          model='silero_tts',
                          language=language,
                          speaker=model_id)

model.to(device)

audio = model.apply_tts(text=text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate,
                        put_accent=put_accent,
                        put_yo=put_yo)

print(text)
sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
time.sleep(len(audio) / sample_rate)
sd.stop()
```

Выдаёт ошибку в pycharm:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741795 (0xC000001D)
```

Comment: `Process finished` - это в общем-то не ошибка. Если есть ошибка, то должен быть какой-то стек-трейс питоновский, где много чего написано. Если это есть - покажите.

Comment: @CrazyElf, нет ничего нет, программа запускается и через какое-то время закрывается с кодом: -1073741795, хотя при нормально работе должно быть: 1